# Another pronunciation question

Tags: pronunciation, rosh-chodesh-new-month, vowels-nekudot, pinchas

On *rosh chodesh* we read from the Torah ([Numbers 28:14](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0428.htm#14)):

> וְנִסְכֵּיהֶ֗ם חֲצִ֣י הַהִין֩ יִֽהְיֶ֨ה לַפָּ֜ר וּשְׁלִישִׁ֧ת הַהִ֣ין לָאַ֗יִל וּרְבִיעִ֥ת הַהִ֛ין לַכֶּ֖בֶשׂ יָ֑יִן זֹ֣את עֹלַ֥ת חֹ֨דֶשׁ֙ **בְּחָדְשׁ֔וֹ לְחָדְשֵׁ֖י** הַשָּׁנָֽה׃
>
> And their drink-offerings shall be half a hin of wine for a bullock, and the third part of a hin for the ram, and the fourth part of a hin for a lamb. This is the burnt-offering of every new moon throughout the months of the year.

I wanted to confirm a few pronunciations:

בְּחָדְשׁוֹ = b’chod-sho

לְחָדְשֵׁי = l’chod-shay

I’m working on the kamatz katan without a siddur with special markings. I’m fairly sure about the first one but less so about the second. It is only the kamatz that I’m concerned about.

Comment: If you find my answer helpful, consider upvoting and/or accepting it! 

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition was correct, both are *kamatz katan* and therefore pronounced as *o.* By default, the *kamatz* is a *kamatz katan* in unstressed closed syllables. (Of course there are exceptions.) Both of these two words have an ultimate stress as the cantillation marks show, and the syllables in question are closed, so you should say *[bechodsho]* and *[lechodshei],* but you can also check it at [this site](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%AA_%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%A1/%D7%98%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D) if you want, where the *kamatz katan* is explicitly marked.